# simple archery game in python

Tags: python

I'm just starting out with python and I'm trying to make a little archery game.  However, it creates an error at this point:  d = math.sqrt(x*x + y*y) (i.e. the distance between the new point and the original center of the cirlce)  Any ideas on why this doesn't work?

```
def archery():

    win = GraphWin("Archery Game", 500,500)
    win.setCoords(-50, -50, 50, 50)

    circle1 = Circle(Point(0,0), 40)
    circle1.setFill("white")
    circle1.draw(win)

    circle2 = Circle(Point(0,0), 35)
    circle2.setFill("black")
    circle2.draw(win)

    circle3 = Circle(Point(0,0), 30)
    circle3.setFill("blue")
    circle3.draw(win)

    circle4 = Circle(Point(0,0), 25)
    circle4.setFill("red")
    circle4.draw(win)

    circle5 = Circle(Point(0,0), 20)
    circle5.setFill("yellow")
    circle5.draw(win)

    score = 0

    for i in range(5):
        p = win.getMouse()
        p.draw(win)
        x = p.getX
        y = p.getY

        d = math.sqrt(x*x + y*y)

        if 40 >= d > 35:
            score = score + 1

        elif 35 >= d > 30:
            score = score + 3

        elif 30 >= d > 25:
            score = score + 5

        elif 25 >= d > 20:
            score = score + 7

        elif 20 >= d >= 0:
            score = score + 9
        else:
            score = score + 0

        print("Your current score is:", score)

    win.getMouse()
    win.close()
```

Comment: what error do you get? Did you import math?

Comment: Small hint: you can raise a number in Python with `**`.

Comment: It looks like p.getX and p.getY should be "p.getX()" and "p.getY()".  I'm assuming that your trying to multiply and add together the getX and getY functions instead of the numbers those functions would return.

Comment: Thanks Mike!  That was it.  Just forgot about the parentheses...silly me

Comment: I hate to be claiming points, but it would be better if you accepted an answer, since you/Mike solved it.

Answer (score 4):

```
    x = p.getX
    y = p.getY
```

will return the function `getX` and `getY` instead of executing it. As Mike Steder said, try `getX()`, that should return a value.

Answer (score 1):

First, you probably need to do:

```
x = p.getX()
y = p.getY()
```

i.e. call the functions and use the return value, instead of using the functions themselves.

Second, you can change the `math.sqrt(x*x + y*y)` call to:

```
d = math.hypot(x, y)
```

Comment: `(x*x + y*y) ** 0.5` can be inlined by the Python compiler, saving a global lookup to hypot, and a function call.

Comment: @Paul: yes, it can be inlined, but does it? Neither 3.1.1+ (r311:74480) nor 2.7.1 (r271:86832) do; I don't know about later versions.

Comment: >>> z = lambda x,y:(x*x + y*y)**0.5
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(z)

Comment: Maybe instead of "inlined" I should have said "compiles to bytecode"

Comment: @Paul: I understood what you meant, although I see you couldn't know that. With your suggestion, I get no different results than the plain `dis.dis(compile("(x*x+y*y)**0.5", "", "eval"))` that I already tried in 3.1.1+ and 2.7.1 (the versions that I mentioned). Your comment applies to some version of Python and later, and this needed to be explicit.